Chrome extension is breaking and giving the error - extension reloaded too many times
I have created a chrome extension that basically scrapes images from a website and then sents it to a third party api for image-processing. While working with the api i am getting an error that the extension has loaded multiple times.
I don't want the error of extension being loaded multiple teams , i believe the issue has to do with chrome.runtime.reload() function
This is my service-worker.js file
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(request)
        if (request.isExtensionLoaded === true){
            console.log('reloaded')
             chrome.runtime.reload();
            
         }
            
    }
);

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {
    chrome.storage.sync.clear();
    chrome.runtime.reload();
    chrome.storage.sync.set({currentState : "initial"});

    
});


Remove chrome.runtime.reload(); Why are you using it? It doesn't seem to make any sense.

Removed the line , and did some more fixes . Now getting only this error:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received
I am making one fetch request in my contentScript.js how to move that request to the background process?

This error is in a different part of the code that's not shown in the question, so I can't comment on that. As for fetch(), see this example.
